# adding jar libraries into jar file

Tags: java, maven

I am doing a maven project. Everything is fine when compiling and running my project in an idea, but whenever I create jar file, my external jar files in web/lib/ cannot be copied into the jar file. Why this occurs ? Can I insert my all files into the jar file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I found solution.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
 
        <finalName>HelloWorld</finalName>
 
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.gui.launcher.LauncherMain</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
 
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
 
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase>
            <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
                <!-- goals == mojos -->
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) descriptor of [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) something like this:

```
</project>
 ...
 <build>
      ...
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest> <!-- requires for executable Jar -->
                  <mainClass>org.my.main.MainClass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef> <!-- final Jar will have this text appended -->
              </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ....
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I have already used this plugin. I am using Symmetricds jar files in my project, but I could not see these jar files in the jar file. Symmetricds jar files in web/lib directory.

Comment: @Muhammed Yüce, Are these Symmetricds jar files added as dependencies in your pom.xml?

Comment: NO, they did not. Because these jar files are special to Symmetric Ds which provides synchronization between two database. I just want to add the folder which contains jar files, into executable jar file.

Comment: @Muhammed Yüce -- So, you need to add those Jars as dependencies. Since they are not publicly available, you need to install them in your local repo like `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar` and add it to dependencies list. They will be available in the package. see here http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html you can also use one-jar to manually create a jar bundle see here http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: My folder is under src folder. This link shows how we can add src folder : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831831/maven-to-copy-jar-when-adding-dependencies